# Get all elements between two div and insert before specific div

Tags: jquery

How can I select all elements between two div and insert them before a specific div named "module-more-comments"?

Before it was easy:

```
jQuery(data).find( "ul.commentlist" ).children().appendTo('ul.commentlist');
```

This my new code:

```
<section class="comment-box">

    <div class="comment-form">form comment</div>

    <article>comment 1</article>
    <article>comment 2</article>
    <article>comment 3</article>
    <article>comment 4<ul class="children"><article>comment 4 children</article></ul></article>
    <article>comment 5</article>
    <article>comment 6<ul class="children"><article>comment 6 children</article></ul></article>
    <article>comment 7</article>

    <div class="module-more-comments">button load more comment</div>

</section>
```

I have a solution:

```
jQuery(data).find('.comment-form').nextAll().not('div.module-more-comments').insertBefore('.module-more-comments');
```

Comment: ... And what happens when you run this code?

Comment: i want use other methods you can see im use article tag and there is no wrapper

Comment: `isertAfter` doesn't seem right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change `isertAfter` to `insertAfter`. This appears to be a typo and would explain why your error message states the function does not exist.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I made the suggestion as a comment, and the OP said it fixed his issue, so I just made a quick post as the answer to tie off the issue.